# c# Instance of T

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to make a genric code to serialize and deserialize any object that implement a specific interface. The problem is that  I need to create an instance of an object before I can call the .Deserialize() because you can't use a static function in an interface. Now my Question is how do I make an instance of T ? or is there a better way to achieve my goal ?

> ```
> public static class Serializer
> {
>     public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T Obj) where T : Data;
>     public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] Data) where T : Data
>     {
>         //Here I need to something like:  new T().Deserialize(Data);
>     }
> }
> public interface Data
> {
>     public byte[] Serialize<T>(T obj);
>     public T Deserialize<T>(byte[] Data);
> ```

```
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Serializer.Deserialize<Dummy>(new byte[20]);
    }
}
class Dummy : Data
{

}
```

Comment: The fact that you need a (throw-away) instance indicates that there are some design issues..

Comment: Make sure all interface names start with the capital letter `I`. Like `IData`, and not just `Data`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman What's the Better Design then ? I want to have a method that can serialize any class that implements the interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update** 
Fixed the code/typos

Use the `new()` keyword

```
public interface IData
{
    public byte[] Serialize<T>(T obj);
    public T Deserialize<T>(byte[] Data);
}
public static class Serializer
{
    public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T Obj) where T : IData;
    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] data) where T : IData, new()
    {
        T res=new T();
        res.Deserialize<T>(data);
        return res;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Serializer.Deserialize<Dummy>(new byte[20]);
    }
}
class Dummy : IData
{

}
```

Comment: This does answer the direct question. But what if `T` is IDisposable, or just generally expensive?

Comment: Was just writing same thing. Note that public parameterless constructor will be mandatory, but if serialization is required, that's not a major constraint.

Comment: Just wanted to quietly mention a minor typo that you have access modifiers on the `Data` `interface` methods which you obviously copied from the question :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman: if `T` is disposable then hopefully the `Disposed()` method will be called by the destructor, or the author can write their own destructor with the `~Data()` method.

Comment: @ja72: That would not always be acceptable. But IDisposable objects usually aren't serializable anyway. That leaves the 'expensive' argument.

Comment: Of course where `T` implements `IDisposable` you can add something like `if (T as IDisposable != null) { T.Dispose(); }`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: So what if it is expensive? It might not matter. It does not seem to be a concern in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) which is for this purpose rather then creating your own.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I considered that but I thought this might really be the answer as this seems to be creating something that already exists. Do you still disagree...I have no problem changing this to a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If your types all have a default constructor or if it's sensible for them to have one you can simpky add a constraint to the t argument requesting a default parameter and the code you've commented out is then legal

```
  public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] Data) where T : Data, new()
        {
            new T().Deserialize(Data);
        }
```

Comment: Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint. 
This is why I asked the question, I tried this way but got error.

Comment: @Svexo , Ow I forgot the , new()

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Data val = System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) as Data;
```

And then

```
   val.Deserialize(Data);
```

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Activator' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Reflection' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 
Do  I need to include a reference ?

Comment: if you are going to really on a default constructor anyways then why not make it a generic constraint on T which would then make new T() legal and would fail compile time instead of run time in the case the type does not have adefault constructor

Comment: @Svexo, sorry it's System.Activator.  I updated for that.  And Rune FS is right, you should make a constraint on T to ensure this works.